# Is there a way to get a kubernetes CRD schema with a kubectl command?

Tags: kubernetes, vault, kubernetes-custom-resources

A way to get the schema using as an example `secretproviderclasses.secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io` i would use the command `kubectl describe crd secretproviderclasses.secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io` and get as a result:

```
Name:         secretproviderclasses.secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io
Namespace:
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  controller-gen.kubebuilder.io/version: v0.9.0
              helm.sh/resource-policy: keep
API Version:  apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
Kind:         CustomResourceDefinition
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-10-11T15:27:15Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:controller-gen.kubebuilder.io/version:
      f:spec:
        f:conversion:
          .:
          f:strategy:
        f:group:
        f:names:
          f:kind:
          f:listKind:
          f:plural:
          f:singular:
        f:scope:
        f:versions:
    Manager:      helm
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-10-11T15:27:15Z
    API Version:  apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:acceptedNames:
          f:kind:
          f:listKind:
          f:plural:
          f:singular:
        f:conditions:
          k:{"type":"Established"}:
            .:
            f:lastTransitionTime:
            f:message:
            f:reason:
            f:status:
            f:type:
          k:{"type":"NamesAccepted"}:
            .:
            f:lastTransitionTime:
            f:message:
            f:reason:
            f:status:
            f:type:
    Manager:      kube-apiserver
    Operation:    Update
    Subresource:  status
    Time:         2022-10-11T15:27:15Z
    API Version:  apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
    Manager:      kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-10-11T15:27:38Z
    API Version:  apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:helm.sh/resource-policy:
    Manager:         kubectl-patch
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2022-10-12T16:02:53Z
  Resource Version:  123907610
  UID:               4a251e0a-97fc-4369-903f-9aa9a13469c1
Spec:
  Conversion:
    Strategy:  None
  Group:       secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io
  Names:
    Kind:       SecretProviderClass
    List Kind:  SecretProviderClassList
    Plural:     secretproviderclasses
    Singular:   secretproviderclass
  Scope:        Namespaced
  Versions:
    Name:  v1
    Schema:
      openAPIV3Schema:
        Description:  SecretProviderClass is the Schema for the secretproviderclasses API
        Properties:
          API Version:
            Description:  APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation of an object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest internal value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#resources
            Type:         string
          Kind:
            Description:  Kind is a string value representing the REST resource this object represents. Servers may infer this from the endpoint the client submits requests to. Cannot be updated. In CamelCase. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#types-kinds
            Type:         string
          Metadata:
            Type:  object
          Spec:
            Description:  SecretProviderClassSpec defines the desired state of SecretProviderClass
            Properties:
              Parameters:
                Additional Properties:
                  Type:       string
                Description:  Configuration for specific provider
                Type:         object
              Provider:
                Description:  Configuration for provider name
                Type:         string
              Secret Objects:
                Items:
                  Description:  SecretObject defines the desired state of synced K8s secret objects
                  Properties:
                    Annotations:
                      Additional Properties:
                        Type:       string
                      Description:  annotations of k8s secret object
                      Type:         object
                    Data:
                      Items:
                        Description:  SecretObjectData defines the desired state of synced K8s secret object data
                        Properties:
                          Key:
                            Description:  data field to populate
                            Type:         string
                          Object Name:
                            Description:  name of the object to sync
                            Type:         string
                        Type:             object
                      Type:               array
                    Labels:
                      Additional Properties:
                        Type:       string
                      Description:  labels of K8s secret object
                      Type:         object
                    Secret Name:
                      Description:  name of the K8s secret object
                      Type:         string
                    Type:
                      Description:  type of K8s secret object
                      Type:         string
                  Type:             object
                Type:               array
            Type:                   object
          Status:
            Description:  SecretProviderClassStatus defines the observed state of SecretProviderClass
            Properties:
              By Pod:
                Items:
                  Description:  ByPodStatus defines the state of SecretProviderClass as seen by an individual controller
                  Properties:
                    Id:
                      Description:  id of the pod that wrote the status
                      Type:         string
                    Namespace:
                      Description:  namespace of the pod that wrote the status
                      Type:         string
                  Type:             object
                Type:               array
            Type:                   object
        Type:                       object
    Served:                         true
    Storage:                        true
    Deprecated:                     true
    Deprecation Warning:            secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1 is deprecated. Use secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1 instead.
    Name:                           v1alpha1
    Schema:
      openAPIV3Schema:
        Description:  SecretProviderClass is the Schema for the secretproviderclasses API
        Properties:
          API Version:
            Description:  APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation of an object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest internal value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#resources
            Type:         string
          Kind:
            Description:  Kind is a string value representing the REST resource this object represents. Servers may infer this from the endpoint the client submits requests to. Cannot be updated. In CamelCase. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#types-kinds
            Type:         string
          Metadata:
            Type:  object
          Spec:
            Description:  SecretProviderClassSpec defines the desired state of SecretProviderClass
            Properties:
              Parameters:
                Additional Properties:
                  Type:       string
                Description:  Configuration for specific provider
                Type:         object
              Provider:
                Description:  Configuration for provider name
                Type:         string
              Secret Objects:
                Items:
                  Description:  SecretObject defines the desired state of synced K8s secret objects
                  Properties:
                    Annotations:
                      Additional Properties:
                        Type:       string
                      Description:  annotations of k8s secret object
                      Type:         object
                    Data:
                      Items:
                        Description:  SecretObjectData defines the desired state of synced K8s secret object data
                        Properties:
                          Key:
                            Description:  data field to populate
                            Type:         string
                          Object Name:
                            Description:  name of the object to sync
                            Type:         string
                        Type:             object
                      Type:               array
                    Labels:
                      Additional Properties:
                        Type:       string
                      Description:  labels of K8s secret object
                      Type:         object
                    Secret Name:
                      Description:  name of the K8s secret object
                      Type:         string
                    Type:
                      Description:  type of K8s secret object
                      Type:         string
                  Type:             object
                Type:               array
            Type:                   object
          Status:
            Description:  SecretProviderClassStatus defines the observed state of SecretProviderClass
            Properties:
              By Pod:
                Items:
                  Description:  ByPodStatus defines the state of SecretProviderClass as seen by an individual controller
                  Properties:
                    Id:
                      Description:  id of the pod that wrote the status
                      Type:         string
                    Namespace:
                      Description:  namespace of the pod that wrote the status
                      Type:         string
                  Type:             object
                Type:               array
            Type:                   object
        Type:                       object
    Served:                         true
    Storage:                        false
Status:
  Accepted Names:
    Kind:       SecretProviderClass
    List Kind:  SecretProviderClassList
    Plural:     secretproviderclasses
    Singular:   secretproviderclass
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-10-11T15:27:15Z
    Message:               no conflicts found
    Reason:                NoConflicts
    Status:                True
    Type:                  NamesAccepted
    Last Transition Time:  2022-10-11T15:27:15Z
    Message:               the initial names have been accepted
    Reason:                InitialNamesAccepted
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Established
  Stored Versions:
    v1
```

Events:

Which is really verbose and hard to read, so is there some command that returns a json schema with examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of something what returns you an example directly. But you could use `kubectl explain` to get information about the fields of the api-resources schema:

e.g.

```
$ kubectl explain secretproviderclasses.secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io
```

To get the fields listed in a recursive way, use:

```
kubectl explain secretproviderclasses.secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io --recursive
```

Some operators also provide examples of their provided CRDs in the `alm-examples` annotation of their ClusterServiceVersion. So maybe this could be another way for you.

Comment: Great! This is something that i've used before and was exactly what i was trying to remember. The thing is for example in this particular case       parameters <map[string]string> is not very helpful. But still, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is also a script called CRDextractor from datree.io : https://github.com/datreeio/CRDs-catalog#crd-extractor

It's actually the usage i was looking for when landing on this question